# Redirect user to url stored in variable (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, redirect

Probably a stupid question but I don't often use javascript and was puzzled why the following code doesn't work..

```
var loc = document.forms["myForm"]["sites"].value;
//loc = 'http://www.sites.com'
window.location(loc);
```

I've done quite a few searches and was surprised to see this hadn't come up before.

Thanks,

Comment: This is called from:  <form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="va()" method="post">

Answer (score 2):

`window.location` is an object, not a function.

Try this instead:

```
window.location.href = loc;
```

or if you want to replace the current history entry:

```
window.location.replace(loc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
window.location.href = loc
```

Comment: Well you can try `window.top.location.href = loc` but it's strange. Everything should work.

Comment: <select name="jump" onchange="window.top.location.href=+this.value;">
<option value="http://site.net/"></option>
</select>

Comment: you forget `http` in site url

Comment: yeah, that was just fast typing.  I've no idea why this is not working

Comment: try this `<select name="jump" onchange="window.top.location.href=this.value;"><option value=""></option><option value="http://site.net/">My site</option></select>​`